# Chat in local network without main server

Tags: wcf, chat, communication, lan, tcp

How can I construct chat application, without main server?
I think about hosting `WCF service` on each computer that connect to network, and trying to connect in loop on all available hosts in `LAN`. Simple scenario after launching my chat application:

- start host chat wcf service
- connect my client to my own service
- search available hosts in `LAN` (e.g if is open on the appropriate port)
- trying to connect to chat wcf service hosted on them
- other machines are conecting to my service

To sending messages each machine use it's own service.
Each service is storing connected clients, and removes user that is disconnected.

I don't like this solution too much, so maybe do you have some better idea?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this my best bet will be 
implement a small UDP boardcast on each WCF Service so each client knows whenever any new client gets connected.
The UDP can also be implemented with WCF Discovery

Comment: But in general is solution with WCF the good one? Maybe some another way?

Comment: The other solution is to write raw sockets apps that can serve the purpose with very less effort. Check ipmessenger for an example